# Binary choices : Surprising results when performing timing tests

Tags: python, testing, time, binary

When comparing several ways of doing binary tests, I timed (using the timeit module) the usual way of doing a binary test, with if/elif (not else, for comparing equality reasons, even if it's usually else):

```
if condition:
    a+=3
elif not condition:
    a+=1
```

Thus, I tried this :

```
t1=timeit.timeit("""
if 1:
    a=1
elif 0:
    a=2
""",number=1000000)

t2=timeit.timeit("""
if 0:
    a=1
elif 1:
    a=2
""",number=1000000)

print t1,t2
```

And these are the results:

```
%run "c:\users\julien\appdata\local\temp\tmpjhuf2w.py"
0.022503887147 0.0205487676589

%run "c:\users\julien\appdata\local\temp\tmpec5gw5.py"
0.0304157066397 0.0194413797704

%run "c:\users\julien\appdata\local\temp\tmppvd2xw.py"
0.0367008256659 0.0190168297643

%run "c:\users\julien\appdata\local\temp\tmpzr8dep.py"
0.0366070894035 0.0186504372933

%run "c:\users\julien\appdata\local\temp\tmpiiv0gg.py"
0.0338743694611 0.0184653594905

%run "c:\users\julien\appdata\local\temp\tmpqqpxyo.py"
0.0188361993025 0.018510517106

%run "c:\users\julien\appdata\local\temp\tmp8czuqx.py"
0.0299052887436 0.0207660031576

%run "c:\users\julien\appdata\local\temp\tmp2haja4.py"
0.0364606692564 0.0211987636392

%run "c:\users\julien\appdata\local\temp\tmpvqoant.py"
0.0286668753496 0.0185029908368

%run "c:\users\julien\appdata\local\temp\tmps2ao5w.py"
0.0330574271449 0.0184735699661
```

Two points in these results appear illogical to me :

- t1 is always greater than t2.
  It means, that, in a "if, elif" pattern, or rather, here, the elif being verified costs more time than the if being verified. But to check the elif, so, "else if", the program has to check the if first ? Thus, there is no way elif being verified could cost less time than if being verified ? Yet, it does.
- t1 varies over time. It's always the same, and it varies by 0.019 to 0.037, which is huge ! I would've thought that my computer would just be allowing more or less power to be python depending over time, but some tests done at the same time (and t2 barely varying) let me thinks it isn't the case.

In short, why do I get those results ? They appear highly illogical to me, and the 2 anomalies are probably connected - which is why I ask them in one question.

Comment: is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: Four, actually, at the bottom of the text.

Comment: I get identical results for t1,t2,t3,t4, if you could actually just make them one or two lines getting directly to what you want to know it would be better.

Comment: Also you are dealing in nanoseconds so it would not take much going on to influence the results

Comment: You shouldn't ask four questions at once. To answer one of them, dictionary lookup is `O(1)`; *that is the whole point of hash tables*.

Comment: Interesting question. But benchmarking doesn't confirm a method's correctness nor is it a good way to decide on personal code convention. Speed is rarely the only thing to consider. The 1 or 2 nanoseconds you might save in the long run will normally be less than the time it takes for you to re understand what you wrote. This is especially true for trivial cases like this.

Comment: @jonrsharpe really? You would have preferred to read that four times just to see a slightly different question at the end. OP has used commonsense here as the answers may be related.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ no, of course not, I would like to have seen four separate questions with the minimal relevant code to each. This format makes it difficult to answer one part in isolation, and then which does the OP accept?

Comment: I guess you are both right. t1 being greater than t2, and t1 varying, should be in the same questions, however a question on dictionnaries is "unrelated", i mean here it's a more general question. Anyway jonrsharpe answered, thanks, i'll edit the question to ask only what's up with these t1/t2 values.
I'm not sure whether is is autorised or not, though, to change fully the meaning of a question, making the early comment appear unrelated ... it seems clearly against the spirit of the website. I'll try, feel free to blame me since i'm new & learning the gears

Comment: Humour me.  What happens if you define t2 before t1?

Comment: 0.0186921738768 0.0190161455585  ;  0.0185248854386 0.018782831211  ;  0.0187992521624 0.0188379098181  ;  0.0185502010709 0.0185714114668  ;  0.0183261235097 0.0186764371329  ;  (t2 still being 2nd place)
What the ... I expected the two values to be swapped, they're identical.